# how can I run two different jquery functions in sequence?

Tags: jquery, function, callback, sequence

I would like to make an effect of swiping images using jQuery.
When I click an image, I want to 1) make the frame width to zero, 2) change to another image, and 3) make the frame width to 100% again. I used the following code, and whatever I do, the image changes first before the frame expands back to 100% (1-> 3-> 2). I tried use callback function, but could not figure it out. Any advice please?

```
$("#frame img").click(function(){
    $("#frame").animate({width:"0%", height:"100%"}, "slow"); //1
    $("#frame img").attr({src:"images2.png"}); //2
    $("#frame").animate({width:"100%", height:"100%"}, "slow"); //3
});
```

The following is what I have tried with callback function (and I think it's completely wrong):

```
$("#frame img").click(function(){
    $("#frame").animate(({width:"0%", height:"100%"}, "slow"), function(){
         $("#frame img").attr(({src:"images2.png"}), function(){
              $("#frame").animate({width:"100%", height:"100%"}, "slow");
              });
         )};
});
```

Comment: Or is there any way that I can change image src attribute using animate() function in jQuery?

Comment: I added what I've tried above. but I think that's completely wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of jQuery plugins that does what you're looking for... If I find it I'll comment back on this answer. For now here's how you can do it.

```
$("#frame img").click(function(){
    $("#frame").animate({width:0}, "slow", function(){
        $("#frame img").attr({src:"images2.png"}).ready(function(){
            $("#frame").animate({width:$("#frame img").width()}, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```

.ready makes sure the image is loaded before reanimating.

Comment: Like @Tadeck mentioned this code can be optimized by caching the frame and frame's image in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use callbacks (where possible, eg. `.attr()` does not support callbacks):

```
$("#frame img").click(function(){
    $("#frame").animate({width:"0%", height:"100%"}, "slow", function(){
        // a callback executed, when the first animation completes
        $("#frame img").attr({src:"images2.png"});
        $("#frame").animate({width:"100%", height:"100%"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

But your code can be optimized. One of the approaches may look like this:

```
var frame = $("#frame"); // cache frame
var images = frame.find("img"); // cache images within frame
images.click(function(){
    frame.animate({width:"0%", height:"100%"}, "slow", function(){
        // a callback executed, when the first animation completes
        images.attr({src:"images2.png"});
        frame.animate({width:"100%", height:"100%"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

(unless of course the results of `$("#frame")` and `$("#frame img")` do not change over time)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example and tell me if it's OK for you:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

For full reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and read about Complete Function